# How to make the percentage symbol smaller than the number?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, font-size, pie-chart

I need to make the "%" (percentage) symbol smaller then the number for data series labels.  Right now they are the same size.  See my sample code at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ottster/pxwpaLyL/5/).

Currently I have this text rendering code, but it renders all text at `62%`; I need to single out the "%" and make it smaller.

```
// Render the text
chart4.renderer.text(chart4.series[0].data[0].percentage + '%', 44, 85).css({
    width: circleradius * 2,
    color: '#515151',
    fontSize: '32px',
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
})
```

Comment: Is that a javascript function?  (I believe so.)  If it is, it could be helpful to add 'javascript' to the tags.

Answer (score 4):

From their [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting):

> HTML IN HIGHCHARTS
>
> Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following tags are supported:  `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<br/>`, `<span>`. Spans can be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is shared with SVG is handled.

So, you can use a `<span>` tag inside the text. e.g.

```
chart4.renderer.text( 
    chart4.series[0].data[0].percentage + 
    '<span style="font-size: 22px">%</span>', 44, 115).css({
```

and it converts any supported style attributes into the appropriate svg code.

Comment: Perfect that's what I needed.  Thank you for a quick respond.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML code `&#65130;` will give you a smaller percentage sign: ﹪.  It's also unicode FE6A, if you need to use a character conversion method.

Comment: Smart thinking, out of the box :D.